# Why i m getting Error: java.io.IOException: invalid header field

Tags: java, web-services, resteasy

Hear it's my pojo class for student...

```
 public class Student {

 private int id;

 private String name;

 private String address;

 private String gender;

 private String emailId;

 private String contactNo;
//setter getter
```

And its i would develop a list class of student below:

```
public class StudentList {

@XmlElement
private List<Student> slist ;

public StudentList(List<Student> slist){
    this.slist= slist;
}//setter getter
```

And My Service class for Student is below:

```
  public class StudentService extends Application {
@GET
@Path("student/read") 
@Produces("application/json")      
@GZIP  public StudentList readstudent(@Context HttpServletRequest request){

    StudentList slistDetail = new StudentList();

    List<Student> s = new ArrayList<Student>();

    for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
        Student st = new Student();
        st.setId(i);
        st.setName("name "+ i);
        st.setAddress("address "+ i);
        st.setContactNo("12345"+i);
        st.setEmailId("email"+i+"@gmail.com");
        st.setGender("m");

        s.add(st);
    }
    slistDetail.setSlist(s);
    return slistDetail;
}
```

Web.xml`

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</param-name>
  <param-value>com.service.StudentService</param-value>
```

```
 <listener>
  <listener-class>
     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
  </listener-class>
```

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
  </servlet-class>
```

***AND I whould Found Below Error:***

```
java.io.IOException: invalid header field
at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Unknown Source).....
```

So,Please tell ME why should occur this type of error...thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with the packaging of your jar. Also, the full stack trace would be great if there is more to it.

Comment: It's not working if possible then please give me idea for which jars i will missing...or what is the actual problem..

Comment: also tell us more about the server you are using and the environment where the application is ruuning

Comment: i am using tomcat 6.0 server..

Comment: You posted the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801281/i-am-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-invalid-header-field. You could edit it instead of asking new question.

Comment: @thatidiotguy :  PLease tell me whay i m getting java.io.IOException: invalid header field...what i exactly missing...